# Powershell delete text in string that does not match conditions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a text file that I need to go through line by line and delete any text that is in quotation marks and does not match one of the following values:

- 192.168.10.1
- 192.168.11.1
- 192.168.12.1
- 192.168.13.1

My initial file would look something like this:

IPADDRESS "192.168.10.1" "192.168.11.1" "192.168.12.1" "192.168.13.1" "10.0.0.1"
IPADDRESS "192.168.10.1" "192.168.11.1" "127.0.0.1" "192.168.12.1" "192.168.13.1"

and I would like my output to be similar to the following:

IPADDRESS "192.168.10.1" "192.168.11.1" "192.168.12.1" "192.168.13.1"
IPADDRESS "192.168.10.1" "192.168.11.1" "192.168.12.1" "192.168.13.1"

I've experimented with using the -replace option, regular expressions, using the trim option, using a filter, using the -match option, to varying degrees of success, but I keep hitting a brick wall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the line, remove unwanted parts with a regex pattern and assemble back the line:

```
Get-Content ip.txt | Where-Object {$_} | Foreach-Object {
   $line=$_.Split()
   $line[0] + ' ' + ($line -match '"192\.168\.1[0-3]\.1"') -join ' '
}
```

Comment: thanks for your assistance, unfortunately I'm getting the following error when trying that code: Method invocation failed because [System.String[]] doesn't contain a method named 'Split'. Am I missing something? Also, is there anyway of combining the regex matches to search for all the four values at once? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edited version @shay, that's put me in the right direction for what I need.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have blank lines in the file? I added a filter to ignore them. Give it a try. The regex pattern takes care of the ip range you specified.

Comment: No blank spaces, however I modified the regex to suit my exact needs, and with the help of your code it's working perfectly.  I wouldn't have had a clue where to start with the split and join etc.  Thanks a lot for your help